# How to locally validate DNSSEC?

Tags: linux, dns, dnssec

I want to simulate the process of chain of trust validation locally , I do the following :-

1) signed my zone.

2)  unbound installed , but i can not configure it for DNSSEC validation could you help ?

- How can i set unbound to see and validate my zone.
- How to add my ds to server ?

How to set ad flag for dig queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer, since I'm not familiar with unbound.

`DS` belongs on the server(s) *delegating to* your zone's servers, not on your zone's server(s). As you probably know, the content of a `DS` record is a hash of `DNSKEY` records in your zone. The `DS` is then signed by the parent zone, which by that verifies that it knows what (some of) your `DNSKEY`s look like.

The `+adflag` command line switch tells `dig` to set the `AD` bit in the query. However, setting that bit is the default, so you usually don't need to ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need, but you can verify the chain of trust interactively at the terminal with `dig +sigchase` .